# Filter kendo datasource by month

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource, datefilter

I have a kendo datasource for which the data needs to be filtered by the selected month. Can a custom filter be applied to the datasource to achieve the same?

My datasource looks somewhat like this:

```
new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: [{name:"Bill", dob:"01/02/1980"},
                        {name:"Bob", dob:"05/06/1981"},
                        {name:"Johnny", dob:"01/08/1980"},
                        {name:"James", dob:"09/10/1989"}]
            });
```

*The dates are converted to string in the format mm/dd/yyyy*

I need to apply a filter so as to retrieve the two records whose dob is on Jan 1980 here.

Comment: `dob` format is `dd/mm/yyyy` ?

Comment: No it is "mm/dd/yyyy"

Answer (score 0):

You can try applying a complex filter as in this code:

`filter: {
                  logic: "and",
                  filters: [
                    {field: "dob", operator: "contains", value: "01"},
                    {field: "dob", operator: "contains", value: "1980"}
                  ]
                }`

Here you can find a sample [dojo page](https://dojo.telerik.com/ofukU).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the .filter() on the DataSource,

```
dataSource.filter( { field: "dob",  value: "01/02/1980" });
var filteredItems = dataSource.view();    
console.log(filteredItems); //This should return all the matched items
```